# ERROR [42000] [MySQL][ODBC 8.0(w) Driver][mysqld-5.6.44-cll-lve]You have an error in your SQL syntax

Tags: mysql, vb.net, image

HELLO Sorry to bother you but maybe you can help me, I am trying to save an image into a MySQL database but I got an error somewhere and I don't know what else to do.. I am working on VB.net app so here is the code:

```
Private Function Imagen_Bytes(ByVal Imagen As Image) As Byte()
        If Not Imagen Is Nothing Then
            Dim Bin As New MemoryStream
            Imagen.Save(Bin, Imaging.ImageFormat.Jpeg)
            Return Bin.GetBuffer
        Else
            Return Nothing
        End If
End Function
```

This is the code on the "SAVE" button:

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        Try
            Dim SQL As String = "INSERT INTO `ImagenPrueba`(`imagen`) VALUES (?foto)"<--SYNTAX ERROR HERE
            CNN = New OdbcConnection(StrConexion)
            Dim Comando As New OdbcCommand(SQL, CNN)
            Dim IMAG As Byte()
            IMAG = Imagen_Bytes(Me.UserPictureBox.Image)

            Comando.Parameters.AddWithValue("?foto", IMAG)

            CNN.Open()
            If cnn.State = ConnectionState.Open Then
                Comando.ExecuteNonQuery()
            End If
            cnn.Close()
            MsgBox("OKKKK")
        Catch ex As Exception
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message)
        End Try
End Sub
```

And when I try to save the image, the system throw this error:

> ERROR [42000] [MySQL][ODBC 8.0(w) Driver][mysqld-5.6.44-cll-lve]You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '?foto)' at line 1

Any help that you can give me THANK YOU for it.

Comment: I think the format of the parameter name is wrong (ie, `@foto`), but I don't use MySql enough to be sure.

Comment: I've been trying also with @foto but I got the same error :(

Comment: Do you have to use ODBC? If not use the dedicated MySQL provider for ADO.NET, i.e. Connector/Net. You can then use @ as a parameter prefix, which they did to be more like the Microsoft providers. Otherwise, I think that you need to use a colon, but I'm not much of a MySQL user either, so I'm not 100% sure.

Comment: I see that you are using `OdbcConnection`, so maybe you simply cannot use **named parameters**. Instead, you may have to use `?` as placeholder, which mean parameters must be in the right order (when you have more than one). You have to check the documentation related to the libraries you are using. With a dedicated Mysql driver you would probably be able to use named parameters.

Comment: I was able to solve the problem myself after a little while, so for some reason you can't use named parameters as you said with the ODBC library, instead I just used the MySQL references and BANG! everything is working fine now haha, thank you so much anyway to all of you